# Подтягивание элементов к верху экрана в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView` в котором есть элементы - сообщения чата. Каждому из них соответствует дата. Мне нужно сделать так что  бы при прокручивании сообщения дата сообщения всегда подтягивалась к верху активити, а когда подтягивалась новая дата - то старая исчезала а новая становилась на ее место. Не могу точно сформулировать, может кто знает как лучше сформулировать - прошу редактировать. 
Вопрос:  можно ли это как то реализовать в пределах одного `RеcyclerView`, или это как то по-другому делается
Вот картинка макета: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите реализацию UltimateRecycleView. Ссылка [присутствует](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView)